# Customizr - Homepage slider between two sidebars

Tags: wordpress, slider, sidebar

Is it possible to put the slider of the homepage between two sidebars? I tried to use 2 sidebars layout but they start after the three featured circles pages.

I would like that the sidebars are left and right of the slider.

How can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Im using "Meta Slider" plugin which meets my requirement. You can also set your slider"s width and length between 2 of your sidebars. Here is the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/ml-slider/